# Selected index changed event not being fired in modal popup?

Tags: asp.net, selectedindexchanged

i have the following code that is supposed to run in modal pop up:

```
#region events


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        dt = DataObj.GetDataTable("GetScheduleNames");
        foreach (DataRow myrow in dt.Rows)
        {
            SchedNameLst.Add(Convert.ToString(myrow["ScheduleName"]));
        }
        SchedNameListDD.DataSource = SchedNameLst;
        SchedNameListDD.DataBind();

    }
}

 protected void SchedNameListDD_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // should be in selected index fired event
    SchedName.Text = SchedNameListDD.SelectedItem.Text;
    string name = SchedNameListDD.SelectedItem.Text;
    dt = DataObj.GetDataTable("GetSchedDetails", name);

    foreach (DataRow myrow in dt.Rows)
    {
        StartTime.Text = myrow["StartTime"].ToString();
        EndTime.Text = myrow["EndTime"].ToString();
    }
    dt = DataObj.GetDataTable("GetSchedDetailsSat", name);
    foreach (DataRow myrow in dt.Rows)
    {
        SatSt.Text = myrow["StartTime"].ToString();
        SatEt.Text = myrow["EndTime"].ToString();
    }
 }


#endregion
```

My selectedIndexChanged Event does not get fired when i change selection of my item in Drop down list .. y is tat so?

Comment: Are you using JQuery dialog? to raise the pop-up?

Comment: I am not using J Query ... already using ModalPopupExtender

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have enabled AutoPostBack on the control i.e. `AutoPostBack = "true"`
2. Make sure the viewstate is enable by setting `EnableViewState="true"` in the Page or UserControl directive

Comment: No nothing is needed. And there is nothing wrong with your code. Check AutoEventWireup="true" in your page.

Answer (score 0):

use onchange="javascript: __doPostBack('**Dropdownlist**','**Patameters**')"

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" Width="270px" Height="24px" EnableViewState="true" onchange="javascript: __doPostBack('ddlPlans','') AutoPostBack="true""
                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPlans_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList> this worked for me.

Comment: set AutoPostBack="false" otherwise your page will refresh two times. use only onchange="javascript: __doPostBack('DropDownList','Arguments')"